# Styled components, adding a nested class

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have the following classes I want to convert into styled components

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;   
  margin: 1em;
  column-gap: 1vw;
  row-gap: 1vh;
} /*div*/

.flex-container .flex-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  
} /*div*/

.flex-item {
  height: 1.7rem;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.flex-container .flex-container{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction: column; 
   margin-bottom: 1vh;
  }
}
```

I have done something like this

```
export const SCCheckoutSuccessButtonsContainer = styled.div<any>`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;   
  margin: 1em;
  column-gap: 1vw;
  row-gap: 1vh;
`;

export const SCCheckoutSuccessButtonsItem = styled.button<any>`
  height: 1.7rem;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
`;
```

Problem is I cant figure out where to add the
`.flex-container .flex-container` block

How do i target that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try  -

```
export const SCCheckoutSuccessButtonsContainer = styled.div.attrs({ className: 'flex-container'})<any>`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;   
  margin: 1em;
  column-gap: 1vw;
  row-gap: 1vh;
`;
```

which will apply the `flex-container` class as well as the styled component generated class, so you can use any existing class names

you can always keep supplying standard CSS with classnames with the likes of the `createGlobalStyle` helper

```
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  .flex-container .flex-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
`
```

https://styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle

The other option, which you may not be able to do as the styled component is trying to reference itself is something like -

```
export const SCCheckoutSuccessButtonsContainer = styled.div<any>`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;   
  margin: 1em;
  column-gap: 1vw;
  row-gap: 1vh;

  ${SCCheckoutSuccessButtonsContainer} {
     // CSS here
  }
`;
```